# Intermittent error: what would cause a video to stop loading between loadstart and durationchange?

Tags: javascript, video, intermittent

I'm in the frustrating situation of having an intermittent error.  When functional, PHP specifies a video and 3 pictures to be displayed.  The video begins playing 800ms after the page loads, and the pictures are displayed immediately upon the end of the video, at which point a user presses a key (corresponding to the location of the picture) and the keypress triggers a function that measures reaction time, stores which picture they selected, and loads the next page, whereupon all of this happens again with a new video and new pictures.

That all works just fine... sometimes.

At other times, I get a blank screen where I was expecting to see the video.  Sometimes it happens right away, sometimes after as many as 15 or 20 successful loads, or anywhere in between.  I'm running Chrome 27.0.1453.93, and tracking errors using Chrome's built-in javascript console.  Even when the video fails to load, there are no javascript errors (with DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">).

To pinpoint where things are breaking down, I've added a bunch of event listeners and used anonymous functions to pass some output to the js console log file to see which stages of the video event are or aren't happening.  Here, at least, is a reliable pattern: every time the video fails to load, loadstart has happened, but durationchange has not. I just can't figure out what the problem is that prevents it from continuing!

I look forward to the responses here, whether they're answers or even just other people corroborating the experience so I don't feel so crazy!  I'll include the two most relevant javascript functions here, but I'm not sure how much good they'll do.

```
<script>

    function playVid(newSource){

           console.log("playVid worked");
           setTimeout(function(){//tells it to wait for some amount of time (below) before doing the next part
               console.log("setTimeout was called");
               document.getElementById("StimClip").innerHTML="<video id='video1'> <source src='" + newSource + "' type='video/mp4'>Something went wrong.  Sorry 'bout that!</video>"; //replace blank.jpg with the appropriate video
               console.log("the inner html was set");
               myAddListener();
               console.log("myAddListener was called");
               var  myVid=document.getElementById("StimClip"); //create a new variable to identify the video
               console.log("the myVid variable was created");
               video1.play(); //play the video

        } //


           ,800); //finishes the setTimeout call by specifying how many msec to wait before executing.


        }

function myAddListener(){
        console.log("myAddListener worked");
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];         
        myVideo.addEventListener('waiting', function(){console.log("I'm WAITING...!")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('suspend', function(){console.log("Nice suspenders.")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('abort', function(){console.log("video was aborted")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('error', function(){console.log("there was an error")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('loadstart', function(){console.log("load start worked")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('durationchange', function(){console.log("the duration changed")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){console.log("metadata was loaded")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){console.log("data was loaded")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('progress', function(){console.log("progress...? ")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('canplay', function(){console.log("video can play")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){console.log("can play through worked")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('playing', function(){console.log("the video started playing")}, false);
        myVideo.addEventListener('ended', ShowPics, false); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh geez.  I'm glad no one else wasted their time trying to answer this.  In case you were wondering, the thing that would cause a video to stop loading between loadstart and durationchange is if that video doesn't exist!  (I had a typo in the filename of one of my videos, and because the order of videos is randomized I couldn't ever tell that it was always failing when it was trying to load the same one.)

Fixed.